# What will happen if element inside div exceeds div width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div tag and this tag contains input and paragraph element. I have specified width of this div element is 320px; and width of input and paragraph element as 450px. I want to know what will happen in this case , will the elements be displayed correctly?

I have this question because div is like bag and the other elements are put inside it will this not overflow?

Here is what I tried

```js
alert("width is"+document.getElementById('spandiv').offsetWidth);
```

```css
.wrapper {
    **width:320px;**
}
.wrapper > input {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: pink;
 **width:450px;**


}
.wrapper > p {
    background-color: grey;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    color:white;
    font-weight: normal;
    **width:450px;**
}

.wrapper > input:hover + #spandiv {
    background-color: grey;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    color:white;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input id="input1" type="text">
            <p id="spandiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut.</p> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"will the elements be displayed correctly?"_ - How about testing it? o.O

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly"? You can specify the overflow of the container div, and it will be displayed that way (scroll, hidden, etc.)

Comment: As others have hinted at, "correctly" is relative depending on what your desire for the display is. There will be a default display, which you can control further with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content inside the DIV tag will adjust its width to the parent element and will fall over the DIV. That behavior can be changed by using the `overflow` CSS property.

More information on that can be found here:

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)